# How does the computer convert between types

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-construction, low-level

So a common question you see on SO is how to convert between type x and type z but I want to know how does the computer do this?

For example, how does it take an int out of a string?

My theory is that a string is a char array at its core so its going index by index and checking it against the ascii table. If it falls within the range of ints then its added to the integer. Does it happen at an even lower level than this? Is there bitmasking taking place? How does this happen?

Disclaimer: not for school, just curious.

Comment: `My theory is that a string is a char array at its core so its going index by index and checking it against the ascii table. If it falls within the range of ints then its added to the integer` that's about right.

Comment: At the risk of sounding overly philosophical, computers don't transform strings into integers, programmers do. If you can come up with a linear time algorithm to parse a string into an integer, you're probably doing it about as good as anyone else.

Comment: lol @zneak that was very zen

Comment: What does a string mean? Someone has to teach our human conventions to the computer to transform a sequence of characters into a numeric value. What's the difference between 123 and 1234 and 0123? As strings they're very similar; the fact that we understand them as different values needs to be written in code.

Comment: @KerrekSB I understand this can get very deep but taken from the most literal sense possible, how does this take place? How does the computer do this? Is there an answer or is my theory correct?

Comment: @AMR: Somebody has to write the code to do it. It's not very hard, and it doesn't even need any arcane notion such as "ASCII". Just a loop suffices to implement the place-value system.

Comment: @KerrekSB but you're answering the question without answering the question. Is this actually what is happening or not? Where is Jon Skeet or someone from the Microsoft Compiler team.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually knowing the character encoding (such as, say, ASCII) *is* important, to understand how to interpret the bytes of the string.

Comment: @AMR zneak's comment is really the best that you can do, given the question.  The compuer isn't doing anything on it's own.  it's not magic, it's just doing what it's instructed to do.  The given example conversion can be defined, by some programmer in any number of ways, such as what is described.  Pretty much single other conversion out there is defined by a programmer, it doesn't just "happen".  It is whatever it's programmed to be.  There isn't anything for the compiler team to tell you about it.  They aren't defining how to convert just about anything.

Comment: Do you people really avoid saying "my computer stores and plays my MP3 files", because what *really* happens is that a programmer has written code to store and play MP3 files, that runs on your computer, and therefore it's the programmer that did it not the computer? Surely it can be understood that if someone asks how a computer does something, they're talking about the whole system including whatever software might be involved.

Comment: @Servy: Not really. You need to know the encoding when you're deserializing a wire format, but if you're working within the system, then you don't need to know. The numeral 0 is `'0'`, etc.

Comment: @SteveJessop So then what do you expect the OP to be looking to hear?  If he already knows that conversions are performed because some programmer wrote a conversion for every single conversion out there, then why is he asking how the computer is able to convert any given type to any other type?  What else is there to ask about, with respect to the general case?

Comment: @Servy: the specific example I think he wants confirmation or denial that the algorithm he describes is used in practice. For the general case of any conversion I can't tell whether the OP is really looking for an exhaustive approach even to the basic types in C# and C++, or an illustrative selection of examples. Possibly the questioner is overlooking that there could be dozens or hundreds of different bits of code on the same machine to do the job of converting strings to integer, and they won't all be identical :-)

Comment: The OP, aka me, didn't know for sure if my suspected process was correct. I didn't know if it handles it in a high level language or if it is handled at the assembly level. I am not retarded @Servy I am fully conscious that the computer does not handle it completely on its own. I know that a programmer once coded this in. I was asking simply where and how things like this take place

Comment: @SteveJessop Exactly, the question makes no sense.  Either the example is the entirety of the question, or it's just an example and it is entirely unclear what he's expecting to hear.

Comment: @Servy: even allowing that the question makes *no* sense (which I do not believe to be true even though I cannot be sure *precisely* what is wanted), I fail to see why you think it's impossible to answer any better than zneak's comment. An answer could *at the bare minimum* cover the part that is clear, i.e. the example. What it does with the rest is less obvious. But responding "your question contains an error of type since computers don't do anything" seems to me a little surreal, albeit an entertaining line of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question can only be answered when restricting the types to a somewhat managable subset. To do so, let us consider the three interesting types: Strings, integers and floats.

The only other truly different basic type is a pointer, which is not usually converted in any meaningful manner (even the `NULL` check is not actually a conversion, but a special built in semantic for the `0` literal).

#### int to float and vice versa

Converting integers to floats and vice versa is simple, since modern CPUs provide an instruction to deal with that case directly.

#### string to integer type

Conversion from string to integer is fairly simple, because no numeric errors will happen. Indeed, any string is just a sequence of code points (which may or may not be represented by `char` or `wchar_t`), and the common method to work through this goes along the lines of the following:

```
unsigned result = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    unsigned c = str[i] - static_cast<unsigned>('0');
    if(c > '9') {
        if(i) return result; // ok: integer over
        else throw "no integer found";
    }
    if((MAX_SIZE_T - c) / 10 < result) throw "integer overflow";
    result = result * 10 + c;
}
```

If you wish to consider things like additional bases (e.g. strings like `0x123` as a hexadecimal representation) or negative values, it obivously requires a few more tests, but the basic algorithm stays the same.

#### int to string

As expected, this basically works in reverse: An implementation will always take the remainder of a division by 10 and then divide by 10. Since this will give the number in reverse, one can either print into a buffer from the back or reverse the result again.

#### string to floating point type

Parsing strings to a `double` (or `float`) is significantly more complex, since the conversion is supposed to happen with the highest possible accuracy. The basic idea here is to read the number as a string of digits while only remembering where the dot was and what the exponent is. Then, you would assemble the mantissa from this information (which basically is a 53 bit integer) and the exponent and assemble the actual bit pattern for the resulting number. This would then be copied into your target value.

While this approach works perfectly fine, there are literally dozens of different approaches in use, all varying in performance, correctness and robustness.

#### Actual implementations

Note that actual implementations may have to do one more important (and horribly ugly) thing, which is locale. For example, in the German locale the "," is the decimal point and not the thousands seperator, so pi is roughly "3,1415926535".

[Perl string to double](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob?f=numeric.c#l848)
[TCL string to double](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-20/tcl/tcl/compat/strtod.c)
[David M. Gay AT&T Paper string to double, double to string](http://www.ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf) [and source code](http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c)
[Boost Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric/real.html)

Comment: Very well thought out. Do you by chance have any resources I can look into for more in depth explanations?

Comment: This is simply addressing the example, of how to convert a character to a string, and isn't addressing the question that the example is meant to speak to.

Comment: @Servy That's true however I figured this was the best I was going to get lol. The question of ever type to every type is a little to abstract for S.O. I think.